# How to hide an element when a div reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page finishes loading another load event is fired within a div tag. So, the DOM within this div tag is refreshed after the page has loaded. When the div tag is refreshed it displays html id like to hide. When I try to hide them when the page loads they are still there. I have tried this code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.myresults-button-exclude').hide();
});
```

This code does not work when the page loads

Comment: not sure what you are asking, show a js fiddle that illustrates the problem

Comment: If the div's content is being filled with the results of an asynchronous ajax call, then the `document.ready` handler is almost certainly being called before the dom is fully loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you just do this in CSS?

```
.myresults-button-exclude { 
   display: none
}
```

Then just use JS when you need to show it... `$('.myresults-button-exclude').show();`

Answer (score 1):

you could just hide them in a css file by default.

```
<style>

    .myresults-button-exclude { display: none }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a class on the element you want to hide with a property of display: none on that class in the CSS?